# What's the best way to select and highlight html on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm looking to make a medium.com like toolbar that when you highlight a selection of text, a tooltip pops up on top of the text. I'm using React and Rails on this.

My thought process was to first develop a way of highlighting the selected text before messing with the tooltip that shows up above the selected text. I figure I need to capture the selected text and send it to state, then search the document for that text and add an html tag with a class that changes background color to yellow. After I do that, I can incorporate this action into a button that'll be on the tooltip so when clicked it'll highlight that text.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
import React from 'react';

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {text: ''}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className = "container" onMouseUpCapture={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
        <h1 className = "headLine" >Medium Markup</h1>
          <p className='editable'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id felis vel sem tristique efficitur. Nunc neque purus, tempor eget urna eu, porttitor congue nulla. Morbi vitae lectus sollicitudin, congue dolor ac, ornare ex. Aenean molestie rutrum mauris, vel ultricies erat pellentesque eget. Nunc at nisi id turpis lobortis ultrices ac eget mi. Cras ac facilisis leo. Vestibulum a enim eget ex tempor pretium. Nunc dignissim bibendum molestie. Fusce imperdiet imperdiet tristique. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Donec nec gravida massa. Fusce tristique, nulla vitae porttitor venenatis, mi sem fermentum metus, sit amet auctor mi nisl nec erat.</p>
        
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleChange(text) {
    var name = document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf(this.state.text);
    console.log(name);
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    this.setState({text: text.toString()});
  }
}

export default Main;
```

I know it's not much but I think I'm way overthinking this here. Any help you guys can give me would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a list of components where each component has its own history or whatever and you show in the home component the list of components.
Then, in home component you have a function to open the toolbar you want, and the toolbar component. So you can pass that function to each item list component, as a prop, and bind it to the home component.

Then each component has an onClick event, and you can call that prop as a function.

I have an example that i did for my personal project:
let activities = this.state.activities.map(function (activity) {

```
        return <div>  <ListItem

                                                      primaryText={activity.name}
                                                      leftAvatar={<Avatar style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}
                                                                          src={activity.icon}/>}
                                                      secondaryText={activity.info}
                                                      rightIconButton={rightIconMenu(element)}
                                                      onTouchTap={element.positionateActivity.bind(element, activity)}
                                                      hoverColor="rgb(0, 188, 212)"
        > <Activity
                    activity={activity}> </Activity></ListItem>
        </div>


    });
return (
        <div>

            <SearchSport activities={this.state.activities} filterFunction={this.filterActivities.bind(this)}/>
            <SelectableList defaultValue={6}>
                {activities}
            </SelectableList>
        </div>
    );
```

All of this is in a "Home" component.
And the from Activity component I have a onClick event where i call the prop onTouchTap as a function.